# Number of values greater than a threshold

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have a matrix `A`. Now I want to find the number of elements greater than 5  and their corresponding indices. How to solve this in matlab without using for loop?

For example if `A = [1 4 6 8 9 5 6 8 9]'`:

- Number of elements > 5: 6
- Indices: `[3 4 5 7 8 9]`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You use `find`:

```
index = find(A>5);
numberOfElements = length(index);
```

Answer (score 4):

You use `sum`, which allows you to get the number of elements with one command:

```
numberOfElements = sum(A>5);
```

Do you really need explicit indices? Because the logical matrix `A>5` can also be used as index (usually a tad more efficient than indexing with `find`):

```
index = (A>5);
numberOfElements = sum(index);
```

For completeness: indexing with logicals is the same as with regular indices:

```
>> A(A>5)
ans = 
     6  8  9  6  8  9
```

Comment: Rody, you might be right about the `sum/find`. However, you have to store the indices anyway. Otherwise you end up computing A>5 twice. Also, `sum` might be faster than `find`, but `A(integer_index)` is faster than `A(logical_index)` because `logical_index` is a 0-1 vector the size of your data, while `integer_index` only holds the necessary values.

Comment: @angainor: Of course, just use `index=A>5; numEls = sum(index);`. Plus: logical indexing is faster than indexing with `find`; try it yourself. As for the memory overhead, that really depends -- `find` returns doubles (64bits per entry) whereas logical indices are bools (8bits, or even 1bit perhaps, per entry) -- no blanket statement can be made about the two in this regard.

Comment: You can cast doubles to uint(16/32/64) - actually you should because indexing with doubles is a rather bad idea performance-wise. Logicals are currently (2011b+) 1 byte. In earlier versions they were 4 bytes :) But yes, it all depends.. Is there any way on SO to post code with benchmarks? I guess I could just answer to this question with a benchmark code I wrote. Or are there alternatives?

Comment: @angainor: Chatroom :) But really, an answer would be best practice I think. I also suspect Matlab implicitly casts double-indices to `uints`, which I suspect is partly where the difference in performance comes from.

Answer (score 2):

Motivated by the above discussion with Rody, here is a simple benchmark, which tests speed of integer vs. logical array indexing in MATLAB. Quite an important thing I would say, since 'vectorized' MATLAB is mostly about indexing. So

```
% random data
a = rand(10^7, 1);

% threashold - how much data meets the a>threashold criterion
% This determines the total indexing time - the more data we extract from a,
% the longer it takes.
% In this example - small threashold meaning most data in a 
% will meet the criterion.
threashold = 0.08;

% prepare logical and integer indices (note the uint32 cast)
index_logical = a>threashold;
index_integer = uint32(find(index_logical));

% logical indexing of a
tic
for i=1:10
    b = a(index_logical);
end
toc

% integer indexing of a
tic
for i=1:10
    b = a(index_integer);
end
toc
```

On my computer the results are

```
Elapsed time is 0.755399 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.728462 seconds.
```

meaning that the two methods perform almost the same - thats how I chose the example `threashold`. It is interesing, because the `index_integer` array is almost 4 times larger!

```
index_integer       9198678x1              36794712  uint32               
index_logical      10000000x1              10000000  logical
```

For larger values of the `threashold` integer indexing is faster. Results for `threashold=0.5`:

```
Elapsed time is 0.687044 seconds. (logical)
Elapsed time is 0.296044 seconds. (integer)
```

Unless I am doing something wrong here, integer indexing seems to be the fastest most of the time.

Including the creation of the indices in the test yields very different results however:

```
a = rand(1e7, 1);    
threshold = 0.5;

% logical 
tic
for i=1:10
    inds = a>threshold;
    b = a(inds);
end
toc

% double
tic
for i=1:10
    inds = find(a>threshold);
    b = a(inds);
end
toc

% integer 
tic
for i=1:10
    inds = uint32(find(a>threshold));
    b = a(inds);
end
toc
```

Results (Rody):

```
Elapsed time is 1.945478 seconds. (logical)
Elapsed time is 3.233831 seconds. (double)
Elapsed time is 3.508009 seconds. (integer)
```

Results (angainor):

```
Elapsed time is 1.440018 seconds. (logical)
Elapsed time is 1.851225 seconds. (double)
Elapsed time is 1.726806 seconds. (integer)
```

So it would seem that the actual indexing is faster when indexing with integers, but front-to-back, logical indexing performs much better.

The runtime difference between the last two methods is unexpected though -- it seems Matlab's internals either do not cast the doubles to integers, of perform error-checking *on each element* before doing the actual indexing. Otherwise, we would have seen virtually no difference between the double and integer methods.

**Edit** There are two options as I see it:

- matlab converts double indices to uint32 indices explicitly before the indexing call (much like we do in the integer test)
- matlab passes doubles and performs the double->int cast on the fly during the indexing call

The second option should be faster, because we only have to read the double indexes once. In our explicit conversion test we have to read double indices, write integer indices, and then again read the integer indices during the actual indexing. So matlab should be faster... Why is it not?

Comment: +1: good test, although I'd love to see how the creation of the indexes affects the times. Mind if I edit?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis oh, go ahead. I hope we arrive at interesting conclusions here.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis The first test has a `b = a()` statement, which I guess is wrong. Does that influence your results? And yes, in my experience matlab explicitly cast doubles to ints (with a check - how else?). Thats why sometimes explicit integers are better used.

Comment: WHOOPS!! classical case of copy-pase-error-propagation. Fixed now :)

Comment: wow, your results are much better than mine...Why's that? What processor do you have? I've got a Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz on my Laptop here. Pretty crappy, dual core.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Core i7-2620M, 2.7GHz. MATLAB Version: 7.14.0.739 (R2012a). That's also dual-core. I guess a bit faster...

Comment: Speedup from double to logical is 1.7 over here, but only 1.3 over there...weird. I'm guessing your CPU is a bit more efficient in the areas where it matters for this :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Maybe matlab version? They do improve things from time to time ;)

Comment: Could be...I've 2010b over here. Oh well.